# Euclidean norm preserving linear transformation: name and characterization?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods

If $T$ is a linear transformation in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ (from itself to itself) that preserve Euclidean norm, then for any $\vec{v}$ then $(T\vec{v})\cdot(T\vec{v})=\vec{v}\cdot\vec{v}$. We already know that orthogonal transformation are example of those. However, this question only concern with preserving just the norm, not the dot product in general. In particular, $T$ need not be invertible.

So is there a special name for those kind of linear transformation? What is a nice characterization of its matrix (under any orthonormal basis) that is easily computable?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: $T:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ must be invertible.  Otherwise, there is a non-zero $v$ such that $\|T(v)\| = 0$.

Comment: Called `orthogonal'...

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isometry

Comment: [See linked question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/169923/proving-that-a-linear-isometry-on-mathbbrn-is-an-orthogonal-matrix)

Comment: Huh, I can't believe I missed that. Well, I guess I would post another question once I figured out what the errors are in my calculation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Notice that a linear transformation $T$ preserves the norm if and only if it preserves the dot product, we can prove this simply using
$$\langle T(u+v),T(u+v)\rangle=\langle u+v,u+v\rangle$$
moreover, the *nice* characterization by the matrix is:
$$A^TA=I_n$$
so we see that $\det T=\pm1$ hence $T$ is invertible.

Answer (score 0):

$T:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ such that $\vert \vert T(x) - T(y) \vert \vert = \vert \vert x - y \vert \vert$ are called *isometries*. Their matrices have determinant equal to $1$, in any base.