# Jacobian of a linear isometry

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^{n^2}\to \mathbb{R}^{n^2}$ a linear isometry.

How to prove that its Jacobian determinant is $1$ ?

Intuitively, it looks natural because an isometry doesn't dilate/contract the area.

Comment: The linear isometry will have a determinant that is constantly $1$ or $-1$.  The Jacobian of the transformation will be that determinant.  Are you asking how to show an orthogonal matrix has determinant $\pm 1$, or how to show that linear isometries are always of the form "multiplication by an orthogonal matrix"?

Comment: @hardmath okay so if i get it right, a linear isometry on $\mathbb{R}^n$ is an orthogonal matrix whose determinant is $\pm 1$, and as the differential of a linear application is the linear application itself, then its Jacobian determinant is $1$.

Comment: The general idea is correct, but your notation and terminology could be clarified.  Why work in dimension $n^2$ instead of simply $n$?  What is the definition of *linear isometry*?

Comment: Closely related: [Proving that a linear isometry on $\mathbb{R}^n$ is an orthogonal matrix](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/169923/proving-that-a-linear-isometry-on-mathbbrn-is-an-orthogonal-matrix)

Comment: @hardmath thanks, that's what i really needed to understand fully. I didn't do linear algebra since a while so i'm a bit rusty on the concept. The dimension $n^2$ should be $n$, it doesn't change much. Initialy, i was looking at linear isometry on matrices $n\times n$, namely : $A\mapsto OAO^t$.

Comment: Okay.  Keep in mind that an isometry means distance preserving, so if we want to apply this notion to matrices, the way we define distances between two matrices is important.