# In linear algebra, why is it that linear transformation is orthogonal if it preserves the length of vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, orthogonality

How are orthogonality and preserving length of a linear transformation even relating? A linear transformation can also be orthogonal even if it doesn't preserve the length of vector.

Comment: A linear mapping preserves orthogonality in $\mathbf{R}^n$ if and only if it multiplies lengths by a nonzero constant. That being said, I'm not sure why exactly we use the word "orthogonal" for mappings that preserve length.

Comment: can you give me an example?

Comment: An example of a mapping with what properties?

Comment: is mapping the same as linear transformation?

Comment: A linear mapping or a linear transformation would mean the same thing.

Comment: An orthogonal linear transformation preserves angles (or equivalently, the inner product, as mentioned in user1781301's answer).  It turns out, thanks to the [polarization identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_identity), this is equivalent to preserving lengths, i.e., they are isometries.  [See here for more](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/169923/proving-that-a-linear-isometry-on-mathbbrn-is-an-orthogonal-matrix).

Answer (score 5):

In general, a linear map $T$ is defined to be orthogonal if $T$ preserves inner products. To be more specific, if $T$ is a function from a vector space $V$ to itself, $T$ is defined to be orthogonal if $\langle v,w\rangle=\langle Tv,Tw\rangle$ for every $v$ and $w$ in $V$.

Now we suppose $T$ is a linear map such that $|Tv|=|v|$ for every $v\in V$. (For simplicity, we assume $V$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$). Consider $$|Tv+Tw|^2=\langle Tv+Tw,Tv+Tw\rangle=\langle Tv,Tv\rangle+2\langle Tv,Tw\rangle+\langle Tw,Tw\rangle$$$$=|Tv|^2+|Tw|^2+2\langle Tv,Tw\rangle.$$ Similarly, we have $$|v+w|^2=\langle v+w,v+w\rangle=\langle v,v\rangle+2\langle v,w\rangle+\langle w,w\rangle=|v|^2+|w|^2+2\langle v,w\rangle.$$ Now, we note $|Tv+Tw|=|v+w|$ and $|Tv|=|v|$ and $|Tw|=|w|$. Thus, we have $$|Tv|^2+|Tw|^2+2\langle Tv,Tw\rangle=|v|^2+|w|^2+2\langle v,w\rangle\implies 2\langle Tv,Tw\rangle=2\langle v,w\rangle.$$ So we have shown that $T$ does preserve inner products.

Comment: Why does T(v) = v if T is orthogonal?

Comment: This is not true in general. What is true is that $|T(v)|=|v|$. This is seen because $|v|=\sqrt{\langle v,v\rangle}$ by definition. Thus, if $T$ is orthogonal, we have $|Tv|=\sqrt{\langle Tv,Tv\rangle}=\sqrt{\langle v,v\rangle}=|v|$.

Answer (score 2):

The square of the length of a vector $x$ is $\langle x,x \rangle$. The length-squared of the image of $x$ after a transformation $A$ is $\langle Ax,Ax \rangle$.

The definition of the adjoint is the map so that $\langle Ax,y \rangle = \langle x, A^T y \rangle$ for all $x$ and $y$. So $\langle Ax,Ax \rangle = \langle x,A^TAx \rangle$. So length is preserved if and only if
$$ \langle x,A^TAx \rangle = \langle x,x \rangle, $$
or
$$ \langle x,(A^TA-I)x \rangle = 0 $$
for all $x$. Hence $A^TA = I$, which is the definition of an orthogonal transformation. Why? Because the same is true of the inner product of any $x$ and $y$: if $A$ is orthogonal,
$$ \langle Ax,Ay \rangle = \langle x,A^TAy \rangle = \langle x,Iy \rangle = \langle x,y \rangle $$

---

It may bother you that the inner product is used to define length. We can actually define the inner product using only lengths, using the *polarisation identity*,
$$ \langle x,y\rangle = \frac{1}{4}(\lVert x+y \rVert^2 - \lVert x-y \rVert^2), $$
so preserving lengths is intimately related to preserving the inner product.

Answer (score 1):

You can talk about orthogonality in an inner product space. Now, orthogonal linear transformations preserve the inner product, i.e. the inner product between two vectors $x$  and $ y $ is the same as the inner product or $Tx$ and $Ty$ where $ T $ is the orthogonal transformation. Now, the inner product induces a norm. Thus, you can easily deduce that an orthogonal linear transformation is an isometry hence preserves length.