# How to know if a matrix multiplication with a vector does not change vector's length!!

Tags: matrices, vectors

I have vector **v** and a matrix **m**

**v' = m * v**

How do I know **length(v')** and **length(v)**  are always same by given matrix m.
What property of m that I should calculate?

Comment: The matrix should be orthogonal.

Comment: Thank you, so **m' = inv(m)** has to be same then?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In linear algebra, why is it that linear transformation is orthogonal if it preserves the length of vectors?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2241247/in-linear-algebra-why-is-it-that-linear-transformation-is-orthogonal-if-it-pres)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your matrices are over the complex numbers then you require them to be 'Unitary' i.e. the inverse is the conjugate of the transpose.

If your matrices are real then they must be orthogonal i.e. the inverse is the transpose.

Comment: Thank you so much, that is all I need