# Condition number example

Tags: matrices, numerical-methods, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, condition-number

I have been learning about the condition number, i.e $$cond_p(A) = ||A||_p||A^{-1}||_p.$$

I've been considering the $2$ norm, and have been thinking about when the condition number is equal to $1$. Of course, when $A = I$ this holds, but I can't think of any other examples?

Thank you.

Comment: Orthogonal matrices are an example.

Comment: The condition number of a matrix can only equal to one if the mapping defined by the matrix is a (scalar multiple of) a linear isometry. That such a matrix is necessarily orthogonal (or unitary in the complex case) in the 2-norm was shown here:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/169923/proving-that-a-linear-isometry-on-mathbbrn-is-an-orthogonal-matrix
Thus, @NigelOvermars example pretty much covers it, up to multiplication by a scalar.

Answer (score 0):

When $A$ is an orthogonal matrix, then $A^T = A^{-1}$.

Hence, for an orthogonal matrix $A$, we have $A^T A = I$.

It follows that $\lambda_{\max}(A^T A) = 1$.

Hence, for an orthogonal matrix $A$, $\Vert A \Vert_2 = 1$.

(Every orthogonal matrix is well-conditioned).

In a similar way, we can show that $\Vert A^T \Vert_2 = 1$.

(If $A$ is orthogonal, then $A^T$ is also orthogonal.)

Thus, $\Vert A^{-1} \Vert_2 = 1.$

Hence, for any orthogonal matrix $A$,

$\kappa(A) = \Vert A \Vert_2 \, \Vert A^{-1} \Vert_2 = 1$.

(Orthogonal matrices are well-conditioned matrices.)