# Is $f(x) = T(x) + b$ with $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $b \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $T_i(x) = \sum_j a_{ji}x_j $ an global isometry?

Tags: linear-algebra, metric-spaces, isometry

Let $a_1, a_2, a_3,\ldots,a_n \in\mathbb R^n$, $a_i = (a_{i1},a_{i2},\ldots,a_{in})$ , $\langle a_i,a_i\rangle = \sum_j a_{ij}a_{ij} = 1$ and if $i \neq k$ then $\langle a_i,a_k\rangle = \sum_j a_{ij}a_{kj} = 0$.
If $T$ is a function from $\mathbb R^n$ to $\mathbb R^n$ defined by $T(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n) = (y_1, y_2,\ldots,y_n)$ where $y_i = \sum_j a_{ji}x_j$. Then $T$ is an global isometry. It's easy to prova that $d(x,y) = d(T(x),T(y))$ and $T$ its bijective because $ker(T) = {0}$.
Therefore it's easy to prove that $d(x,y) = d(T(x) + b, T(y) + b)$, but $T(x) + b$ it's not an linear map. How can i prove that $T(x) + b$ is surjective?

And how can i prove that every global isometry $f$ from $\mathbb R^n$ to $\mathbb R^n$  have form  $f(x) = T(x) + b$?

Comment: [Linked](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/169923/proving-that-a-linear-isometry-on-mathbbrn-is-an-orthogonal-matrix?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Google provided me several links. For instance

- Mikael Forsberg "[Isometries of the plane](http://www.linearalgebra.se/pdfs/isometry.pdf)", Theorem 1.4
- Keith Conrad "[Isometries of $\Bbb R^n$](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/grouptheory/isometryRn.pdf)",Theorems 2.1 and 4.1
- "[Isometries in $\Bbb R^n$](http://www.sfu.ca/~mdevos/notes/geom-sym/isom_rn.pdf)", Theorem 16.6
- "[Isometries of the Euclidean Space](http://people.math.gatech.edu/~ghomi/LectureNotes/LectureNotes2U.pdf)", Theorem 1
- Salil Vadhan "[Isometries](https://people.seas.harvard.edu/~salil/am106/fall10/Symmetry.pdf)"
  (only a claim without a proof).

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $f(x)-b= T(x)$ is a linear map that can be expressed as a matrix with determinant 1 or -1.